# How many times should I cut in?

Tags: painting

I am using a water-based paint (based on [Eskaro Akrit 7](http://www.eskaro.ee/?group_id=39&page=81)) to paint interior walls. At this point I have masked the edges of my target area, and have cut in those edges once. The wall is otherwise unpainted — I meant to make multiple coats (two or three).

How do I proceed now? Should I remove the tape, start rolling, and just touch up the edges? Or should I keep the tape, cut in all the edges a second time, and then roll?

Perhaps more generally, what is the right sequence in which to paint edges vs. large areas in multiple coats?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How many times is mostly dependent on the quality of the paint and the particular color.

You want to do it enough times so that it matches the rolled-on areas.

There is no 'one way' to do this, but typically I cut in first, then roll, then touch up as needed.

I don't bother with tape. It's much faster, less messy, and (over time) more accurate to get the hang of using a good brush and cutting in manually. The tape rarely works as well as you want and adds a whole lot of time to the project.